# How to change owner recursivly depending of the actual owner

Tags: powershell, file-ownership

I'm just a beginer with PowerShell but I'm already sure that it's a powerfull language.
I want to make an easy thing with my first script : "Recursivly changing owner of files and folder depending of the actual owner".
But I realize that it will not be as easy as I imagined.
One of my problems is that some files or folder name have [brackets].

Here's my script :

```
$FolderToScan = "D:\Sauvegardes"
$OldOwner = "BUILTIN\Administrateurs"
$NewOwner = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("MON-Domaine","MON-Utilisateur")

$files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $FolderToScan -Recurse

Foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $f = Get-Item -LiteralPath $file.FullName
    $f = $f.GetAccessControl()
    If ($f.Owner -eq $OldOwner) {
        $f.SetOwner($NewOwner)
        Set-Acl -path $file.FullName -aclObject $f
    }
}
```

What do you thing about it ?
Please help.

Comment: What is the problem you are having with file names with brackets?

Comment: I had a problem with brackets but I think it has been solved with `$f.GetAccessControl()`

Actually, I have this error message : `Set-Acl the Security Identifier Is Not Allowed to Be the Owner of This Object` with files and folder that matche with the owner I search.